# EC2 resources unavailable on IAM console

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS and i have free-tier account .I am not able to setup an EC2 instance using IAM console to do some sample projects as a part of AWS bigdata tutorials. I am facing the following issues.

1. Nothing is showing up under the navigation pane and it always displays the following error message

> *An error occurred while retrieving information about your EC2 resources*

2. When I try to create an instance it fails with `Error loading AMI data`.

I tried most of available zones also. Any help is appreciated. I have also included the error screens here.

[Error while loading iam console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwS8g.png)

[Error while trying to launch an instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHX0i.png)

Comment: Submit an [Account & Billing Support request to AWS](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?region=us-east-1#/case/create?issueType=customer-service).  If you have not used EC2 *at all* and you're experiencing this issue, it does not look like a technical support issue -- it looks more like your account might not have EC2 access enabled.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an issue that needs to be referred to vendor account support.

Comment: I raised a case on this but they are not able to solve